# Google map search issue

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular6

Im haveing some issues with this service, it shows me the default map every time I open the modal to modify an adress, so I need to know how to pass the adress param to the service to show me the exactly current location when I open the modal.

This is my implementation

HTML button

```
        <button attr.disabled="true" (click)="openAddress()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-left-0 rounded-right"
            ngbTooltip="Buscar"
            placement="top"
            style="border-radius: 0;">
      <i class="fas fa-search-location"></i>
    </button>
```

Event from component

```
  openAddress() {
let modal = this.modalService.open(MapSearchComponent, {size: "lg"});
modal.componentInstance.addressEmitter.subscribe(data => {
  this.control.setValue(data.completeAddress);
  this.locationEmmiter.emit(data);
});
```

}

Here is where I set the default location on the modal component

```
  setMap() {
let map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, {
  center: {lat: -34.5709303, lng: -58.4455997},
  zoom: 13,
  mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
} as any);
```

Comment: Assuming the set map function is in the MapSearchComponent, then you would pass that as a data option to the modal.

Comment: So (MapServiceComponent,{data:’’}) and then get that data using an Input decorator (don’t forget to import MAT_DIALOG_DATA)